# What is the difference between journald.conf and system.conf

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I know that `systemd` is a mechanism of service management.

But I don't know why there are two config files: `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

For example, in the `system.conf`, I see there is a line: `LogLevel=info`, and in the `journald.conf`, there are some lines:

```
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
```

They look very similar.

What's the difference between both of them?